# Trying to iterate in a item cause: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, typeerror

I'm trying to iterate through a element using this code:

```
$.each(element, function(index, item) {
    ...
});
```

I check `element` type by executing this command `$.type(element)` in Chrome console and I got "object" as output. I check also what has `element` inside using this command `element` and got this as output:

```
[<input type=​"text" name=​"input_color_5[]​" class=​"field_color" data-selector=​"color" data-id=​"color_5" placeholder=​"Color">​]
```

Also I tried all this command from console:

```
element.val() -> return ""
element.attr('data-selector') -> return "color"   
element.attr('data-id') -> return "color_5"
```

If I use instead this other code:

```
element.each(function(index, item) {
    ...
});
```

Then the error turn on:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'each' of undefined

This is how I construct element object:

```
function getDivId() {
    var inputValues = [];
    inputValues.push($('#choices_picker input[type="text"]'));
    return inputValues;
}
```

And I call later in this way:

```
$('#choices_picker').on("click", "#create-variation", function(e) {
    var parent_id = $(this).closest("section").attr("id");
    var element = getDivId(parent_id);

    $('#variations_holder').show();
    $('#variations_holder').html("");
    html = "";
    iterateChoices("", element[0], element.slice(1), 0);
    $('#variations_holder').append(html);
});
```

And finally this is the function `iterateChoices()`:

```
function iterateChoices(row, element, choices, counter) {
    if ($.isArray(choices)) {
        $.each(element, function(index, item) {
            if (counter === 0) {
                row = '<label>UPC:</label> <input style="display: inline-block" type="text" value="" name="pupc[]" />';
                row += '<label>Precio:</label> <input style="display: inline-block" type="text" value="" name="pprice[]" />';
                row += '<label>Cantidad:</label><input type="text" style="display: inline-block" value="" name="pqty[]" />';
            }

            if (choices.length > 0) {
                iterateChoices(row + '<input disabled="disabled" value="' + item.value + '"></div>', choices[0], choices.slice(1), counter + 1);
            }
        });
    } else {
        html_temp = "";
        element.each(function(index, item) {
            html_temp += row + '<input value="' + item.value + '" disabled="disabled"><br>';
        });
        html += html_temp;
    }
}
```

Then I ask myself, isn't `element` a object since I got the error? What is wrong or what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

After read the suggestions by users and identify where the problem was I will explain what I'm trying to do:

1. I have several or just one div's under a wrapper div, this wrapper is `#choices_picker`
2. Inside each div I can have one input or more than one
3. In this step I need to build variations with each input element, for example is I have 3 inputs with values S, M, L then I need to generate something like this:

> ```
> <input name="upc" /><input name="qty" /><input name="price" /><input name="" value="S" />
> <input name="upc" /><input name="qty" /><input name="price" /><input name="" value="M" />
> <input name="upc" /><input name="qty" /><input name="price" /><input name="" value="L" />
> ```

1. Another approach is for example is I have 4 inputs separated by div with values S, M, L and Red then I need to generate something like this:

> ```
> <input name="upc" /><input name="qty" /><input name="price" /><input name="" value="S" /><input name="" value="Red" />
> <input name="upc" /><input name="qty" /><input name="price" /><input name="" value="M" /><input name="" value="Red" />
> <input name="upc" /><input name="qty" /><input name="price" /><input name="" value="L" /><input name="" value="Red" />
> ```

PS: Take into account that I'll never know how many DIV's or how many INPUT's I'll have since they are created on the fly when user clicks a button

Comment: How did you construct `element`? Do you expect it to be a jQuery wrapper object? It seems to be `undefined` instead.

Comment: @undefined yes this is what I think also but how to convert from DOM object to jQuery object in order to iterate it?

Comment: @Bergi see the post again, I edited adding extra information

Comment: Your `getDivId()` function, despite a name that implies that it will return an Id, is returning an array with one element that is a jQuery object. Why are you wrapping a jQuery object in an array?

Comment: Hmmm @nnnnnn you're right I don't, so if I change my code from this `var element = getDivId(parent_id)` to this `var element = $('#choices_picker input[type="text"]')` it will work? Did I understand you?

Comment: Is `getDivId` really the code you're using? You're calling it with an argument from the click handler, but it does not take one. The code you posted actually ensures that it returns an array with a jquery object at index 0, but if it somehow would return an empty array that would explain the exception.

Comment: I thought there is the problem but until now I can't find how to deal with this, could you give me a hand on this? What I need to pass to `iterateChoice()` function is all the `input[type="text"]` that exists in `#choices_picker`

Comment: If you did use `var element = $('…')` then you would also need to change the invocation to `iterateChoices("", element, [], 0);`

Comment: When you call `iterateChoices()` and pass `element.slice(1)` as the third argument that will always be an empty array since `element` is an array with only one element in it.

Comment: @nnnnnn Then I should check before is length is greater than 1 right?

Comment: @Bergi since I change the code to this `var element = $('#choices_picker input[type="text"]');` then this is right or not? `if (element.length > 1) { iterateChoices("", element[0], element.slice(1), 0); } else { iterateChoices("", element, [], 0); }` or I still lost?

Comment: I don't think you want to pass the DOM element (the `<input>`) as an argument to `iterateChoices`, as you cannot iterate over it. Is that really your intention?

Comment: @Bergi no, you're right I don't want that but don't know how to do this in the right way

Comment: What do you want then? Please put a section in your question to describe what the code is expected to do so that we could recommend you better approaches if necessary.

Comment: @Bergi take a look at the edit I made, if you didn't catch something ask me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
 var element = $("#"+parent_id);
```

it will return the element as a jQuery object you can then manipulate.